# Split R dataframe according to number of cases per row

Tags: r, dataframe

How do I split a dataframe like

```
a <- c("a","a","a","b","b","c","c","d","d","d")
b <- c(1,2,3,1,2,1,2,1,2,3)
df <- data.frame(a,b)
```

into single dataframes that contain only cases of equal length, i.e., all cases with three occurrences in a dataframe and all cases with two occurrences into a separate one?

The output should be:

```
dfa
a 1
a 2
a 3
d 1
d 2
d 3

dfb
b 1
b 2
c 1
c 2
```

Comment: can you show us what the output should look like with this input?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at `?split` and `?ave`:

```
split(df, ave(df$b, df$a, FUN = length))
#$`2`
#  a b
#4 b 1
#5 b 2
#6 c 1
#7 c 2
#
#$`3`
#   a b
#1  a 1
#2  a 2
#3  a 3
#8  d 1
#9  d 2
#10 d 3
```

Comment: This works great but if I do this on a large dataframe where I add more than just one column as second argument of the ave function (df$a in the example above) this really takes R ages to process a result. Is there a more efficient way to achieve the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit more involved, but you could use `droplevels` with `table`

```
> tab <- table(df$a)
> lapply(3:2, function(x){
      droplevels(df[df$a %in% names(tab)[tab == x], , drop = FALSE])
  })
## [[1]]
##    a b
## 1  a 1
## 2  a 2
## 3  a 3
## 8  d 1
## 9  d 2
## 10 d 3

## [[2]]
##   a b
## 4 b 1
## 5 b 2
## 6 c 1
## 7 c 2
```